# Make sql field always equal to count from another table

Tags: mysql

What should I do so that a field in mysql is always equal to the `Count`of some fields from another table, so that if that table gets changed then the field also does accordingly? For example:

```
UPDATE table SET this=COUNT(*) ... WHERE ...
```

And if the above was **7** but I Inserted a row in the table, I would want it to automatically update to **8**

Comment: Which MySQL-version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it 2 ways (as far as I know).

1. You can make a [`view`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) which contains the data including the count.
2. You can make a [`trigger`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) to do something when you create a row, update a row and delete a row. This way you have to do the `COUNT` each time a change has occured to that value.

The `view` is slower than the `trigger` because each time you want to use the `view` the query behind the `view` is executed. The `view` is easier to implement and needs less maintanence. Depending in how many ways the `field` your require to count can change it can become more complex.